# How to boot a Raspberry Pi Compute Module 4 (with eMMC ) from a SD card

Tags: raspberry-pi, bootloader, raspberry-pi4

I have a Raspberry Pi Compute Module 4 with eMMC, I'm able to flash from my Ubuntu host the eMMC following the instructions using

- rpiboot
- Imager

I have flashed a SD card using the tool Imager, but when I introduce it in the slot, It is not booting from the SD but from the eMMC. I have used a Jumper in J2, to disable eMMC boot, but nothing happens, and if I remove the Jumper the board boot from the eMMC. How can I make it boot from SD?

Thank you for the info.

Comment: Tell me, do you have a `boot` partition on your `SD`?

Comment: Yes, I have used the Imager tool, this creates two partitions, the boot partition for kernel and the rootfs partition.

mmcblk0     179:0    0  14,9G  1 disk 
  mmcblk0p1 179:1    0   256M  1 part /media/lex/boot
  mmcblk0p2 179:2    0   3,4G  1 part /media/lex/rootfs

Comment: Try to create a bootable USB with https://www.balena.io/etcher/

Comment: and another question, what do you have in the `BOOT` section in the `cmdline.txt` file?
In particular, the line where it is specified is of interest: `root=/`

Comment: The cmdline.txt file has this:
  console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=904a3764-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet init=/usr/lib/raspi-config/init_resize.sh splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles

Comment: Well, I think the problem is, you have another device installed in the `root=` parameter to boot the system, you need to specify the full path to the device where the system is spinning. For example, on my `SD card` in the boot section in the `cmdline.txt` file, the `root` parameter is specified as follows: `root = /dev/mmcblk0p2` where `mmcblk0p2` is the `SD card`. `Kali Linux ARM` system for Raspberry Pi 4B

Comment: For comparison, the full content of the file is:
`dwc_otg.fiq_fix_enable=2 console=ttyAMA0,115200 kgdboc=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext3 rootwait rootflags=noload net.ifnames=0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I asked this question in the RPi forum: "If I have a CM4 with eMMC plugged into a I/O board, can I put in jumper J2 to disable eMMC boot and boot from a microSD instead?"

Here is the answer I received: "the module with an eMMC doesnt have the SD pins wired up, so the microSD slot on the CM4IO board is going nowhere.  you could add your own microSD on the right gpio, but the firmware doesnt support booting from it"

And another answer: "You end up booting to USB mode rather than SD Card - this is a fall back if the eMMC gets corrupted somehow."